# When dateformat parse and format methods are asymmetric?

Tags: java, date-format

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("EEE, d MMM Y HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);

String date = "Mon, 21 Oct 2013 22:21:00 +0400";
dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(date)); // returns "Mon, 31 Dec 2013 22:21:00 +0400"
```

Why the result string differs from input date variable in month and month day?

Comment: Use `y` for your year field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that output, because you are using the wrong format. You should use `y`(lowercase) for *year*, and not `Y` - which is used for [week year](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year)

```
"EEE, d MMM y HH:mm:ss Z"
```